# Изменение значения атрибута JSON файла

Tags: c++, json

Имею **.json** файл, выглядящий следующим образом.

```
{"Settings":{"AutoReload":true,"CheckingUpdates":false}}
```

Необходимость в следующем: изменить значение "Settings - AutoReload" с True на False. Насколько я понимаю, необходимо переписывать .json объект, но как это сделать грамотно - не понимаю. Использую кривой код, при таком весь файл переписывается и в итоге его содержимым становится содержание

```
{"Settings":{"AutoReload":false}
```

Сам код следующий:

```
// Код при запуске/активации программы

std::ifstream fin("img.json");
if (!fin.is_open())
{
    json my_obj;
    my_obj["Settings"] = { {"AutoReload", true}, {"CheckingUpdates", false} 
};

std::string dumped_json = my_obj.dump();
std::ofstream fout("img.json");
fout << dumped_json;
fout.close();


// Код в MainLoop

json new_obj;
new_obj["Settings"] = {
    {"AutoReload", false}
};

std::string new_dumped_json = new_obj.dump();
std::ofstream fout("img.json");
fout << new_dumped_json;
fout.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Код в `MainLoop` создает пустой объект `json` записывает в него `{"Settings":{"AutoReload":false}` и сохраняет в файл. Шаг с чтением содержимого этого файла перед изменением отсутствует.